# Draw Polygon using set latlong from database in googlemaps

Tags: arrays, google-maps, polygon

I am trying to draw polygon in my map but fail. I have set latlng from my database. I already read the tutorial in here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-simple

I am using vb.net on query.

here is my code :

```
function showpolygon(){
       var data1 = "<%= vpolygon %>";
       var ndata1 = data1.split("|");            
       var len1 = ndata1.length;
       var nnama, nlat, nlong, gmbrpolygon;
       var arraypoly = [];
       var arraypoly1 = [];
       var n =0;
       var polygons = [];
       alert ("<%= vpolygon %>");
       for (var i = 0; i < len1; i++)
            {
               ndata11 = ndata1[i].split("~");
               nlat = parseFloat (ndata11[1]);
               nlong = parseFloat(ndata11[2]);
               arraypoly = new google.maps.LatLng(nlat,nlong);  
                //alert(polygons);
               arraypoly1.push(arraypoly);          
               }

        polygons.push(arraypoly1);
        gmbrpolygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: arraypoly1,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35
        });
        gmbrpolygon.setMap(map);
       }
```

I am trying to using a mvc array but an error occurs.

edit :<%= vpolygon %> contain : name~lat~long~numberof|

```
polygon[n] = { location: new google.maps.LatLng(nlat,nlong)};
var polygons = new google.maps.MVCArray(polygon);
```

the error when i am using mvc array is parameter 0: [object][object] and Cannot set property '0' of undefined

and with this code nothing error in console javascript, but the polygon doesn't appear.

Comment: You should include information about the error you are getting.

Comment: What is rendered in the browser for `<%= vpolygon %>`?  What is this `polygons.push(arraypoly1);` for?  And as @Filburt asked, what error is occurring?

Comment: sorry for my question that not have more detail. i already edit the question. thanks for the answer. can u help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function works fine for me when the provided string has the correct format:

```
'some~lat~lng|some~lat~lng'
```

Check if the string has this format, I guess it does have this format:

```
'lat~lng|lat~lng'
```

When it does your function will not work, because you create the LatLngs from the splitted values 2+3 of each portion(note that array-indexes are zero-based), but the result-array will only have 2 items.

You must change:

```
       nlat = parseFloat (ndata11[1]);
       nlong = parseFloat(ndata11[2]);
```

into

```
       nlat = parseFloat (ndata11[0]);
       nlong = parseFloat(ndata11[1]);
```

---

### `<edit>`

As the format of the data is not the issue here(it's still not clear to me why your first approach without MVCArray did not work), I rewrote your function, it now makes use of MVCArray, supports complex polygons and accepts data and polygon-options as arguments to make this function flexible:

```
function showpolygon(data,options){
       var indexes={lat:1,lng:2},//indexes of lat and lng in the splitted arrays
           delimiters   = ['#','|','~'],//delimiters for data
           paths        = new google.maps.MVCArray(),
           defaults     ={//default polygon options,
                          //will be merged with the options-argument
              strokeColor: '#FF0000',
              strokeOpacity: 0.8,
              strokeWeight: 2,
              fillColor: '#FF0000',
              fillOpacity: 0.35
            }, temp;

       if(options){
          for(var k in options){
            defaults[k]=options[k]
          }
       }

       defaults.paths=paths;
       temp=data.split(delimiters[0]); 

       for (var a = 0; a < temp.length; a++){
               var current=new google.maps.MVCArray();
               temp[a]=temp[a].split(delimiters[1]);
               for (var b = 0; b < temp[a].length; b++){
                 temp[a][b]=temp[a][b].split(delimiters[2]);
                 current.push(new google.maps.LatLng(temp[a][b][indexes.lat],
                                                     temp[a][b][indexes.lng]))
               }

               paths.push(current);          
            }
    return new google.maps.Polygon(defaults);
}
```

sample usage for a simple polygon:

```
showpolygon("name~54~-82~0|name~55.3~-116~0|name~34~-107~0|name~36~-70~0",
            {map:map, strokeColor: '#000000', strokeWeight:4, fillColor:'#00FF00'});
```

sample usage for a complex polygon:(Note the new delimiter `#` , delimiters may be defined via the delimiters-variable inside the function)

```
showpolygon("name~1~1~0|name~55.3~55~0|name~43.2~-11~0#name~24~4|name~39~1~0|name~43~22~0|name~31.5~20.8~0",
            {map:map, strokeColor: '#0000FF'});
```

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/rBE6S/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/rBE6S/)

Comment: thanks for your answer, i am already edit the question. can u help me? this is still  a mystery for me.

Comment: Well, my answer above is redundant, because the data have the correct format. By this, I can't say what's the problem with the code of the function, it works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/TB786/ . Related to the edit, the error says that polygon is not defined somewhere, did you define an array named polygon somewhere? Furthermore this array should contain only LatLng-objects, and they should not be wrapped into another object(as you do). I made a simplified version which uses MVCArray, give it a try: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/N5RU7/

Comment: thanks, i got the solution because of you. set latlng array i have from draw polygon and save them into database and i look into database and find that latlng have a mistake when save into database. thanks a lot.